# Creating a 1-dimensional array without specifying the array elements and the array length in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is it possible to create a 1-dimensional array without initializing the array elements and the  array length in Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

I usually create the empty array first, say

```
array=[];
```

and then append the results, for instance:

```
for cont = 1: 10
  array=[array,cont];
end
```